# Effect of return type being static

Tags: c

What are the possible effect of returning a static type data. And when should we actually use it?

```
static ssize_t
my_read(int fd, char *ptr)
{
    //code from Stevens Unix Network programming. 
      if (something)
         return (-1)
      if (something else)
          return (0)


      return (1)
}
```

why static here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The function is static, not the return type. This means that its name is only visible from within the current compilation unit, which is used as an encapsulation mechanism.

The function can still be called from elsewhere through a function pointer, however.

See also [this discussion on the general `static` keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572547/what-does-static-mean-in-c?rq=1) for more context.

Comment: there is another aspect when returning a data type which is static.

Comment: It means that the identifier is scoped to the current translation unit, but the function can still be called from elsewhere through a function pointer.

Comment: @Algorithmist: There is no such thing as a static data type, in the linkage sense. A "static" class is merely a class with only static members, and has practically no connection with this question.

Answer (score 1):

We use static data type when returning a pointer to a variable created in called function.for e.g

```
float * calculate_area(float r) 
{
    float *p;
    static float area;   
    p=&area;   
    area=3.14*r*r;
    return p;
}
```

If you would make area as automatic variable i.e without any type qualifier it would be destroyed when control returns from called function.When declared as static you could  correctly retrieved the value of area from main also.Thus it in order for it to persists its value we make it as static.

Comment: @freedesk are you talking about returning a static data or a static function.I thought you were talking about returning static data from a function.

Comment: This is poor practice, it breaks private encapsulation. Returning pointers to statics are also dangerous because of thread-safety issues, and order of evaluation issues. Because of undefined order of evaluation, you don't know what will happen if you call this function as for example     printf("%f %f", *calculate_area(1.0f), *calculate_area(2.0f));

Answer (score 0):

By using `static` , Access to static functions is restricted to the file where they are declared
Another reason for making functions static is to reuse the same function name in other files.

```
//file1
static void fun1(void) 
{ 
  cout<<"file1";
} 


// file2
// now if we include file1 and use fun1 in file2 , it
// will show “undefined reference to `fun1’” error as 
// it fun1 is defined static

int main(void) 
{ 
  fun1();  
  getchar(); 
  return 0;   
}
```